# text is not rendered correctly after reopen libgdx app

Tags: android, text, fonts, libgdx, rendering

When I start the app for the first time, the label of the TextButton is displayed correctly:

[Text OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lel9m.png)

But when I press the back Button(app gets closed) and open it again, the text is not rendered correctly:

[Text not OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFiXn.png)

Comment: add your java code for this layout.

Comment: Are you using AssetManager for your BitmapFont ??

Comment: The most probably you have issues with static initialization of your assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems occur mainly when we make resources static.
 According to libgdx wiki don't make your AssetManager or any other resources (like Texture, etc.) static, unless you properly manage them.

E.g. the following code will cause issues:

```
public static AssetManager assets = new AssetManager();
```

This will cause problems on Android, because the life-cycle of the static variable is not necessarily the same as the life-cycle of your application. Therefore the AssetManager instance of a previous instance of your application might be used for the next instance, while the resources are no longer valid. This typically would cause black/missing textures or incorrect assets.

On Android, it is even possible for multiple instances of your Activity to be active at the same time, so do not think you're safe even if you handle life-cycle methods properly!

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem was, that I made my BitmapFont static because I wanted to cache it. I called skin#dispose and skin#dispose called font#dispose - so my font was gone. I use a non static AssetManager now and it works